# How can I increment the day with skipping weekends

Tags: java, date, calendar

How can I increment the day with skipping weekends. I mean if `day=Friday` then `day+1=Monday`. Please take a look at my increment method which I increment a  calendar day and not a Business day

```
public Date  incDay( Date date){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTime(date); 
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
return cal.getTime();
}
```

I need to modify this method for resolve this issue.

Update:

I update my method like this

```
public Date incDay(Date date){
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    // public final static int FRIDAY = 6;
    final int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
    }else{
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

**Main()**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

Date d=incBusiness(new Date(2017, 02, 17));//2017/02/18

}
```

I got 2017/02/18 instead of 2017/02/20

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar class has constants to check the day of the week:

**FRIDAY** is the 6th day of the week, doing an if-else can resolve the issue...

```
    public static void foo() throws ParseException {
    String dateString = "2017/02/17";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");// "2017/02/17";
    Date date = df.parse(dateString);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
    } else {
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
}
```

Comment: What c variable means it's not declare , I have an error on it ?

Comment: Should it be cal...typo??

Comment: and ==FRIDAY doesn't accept it, I have error

Comment: yeap... it must be "cal" as Calendar

Comment: Yeah..it should work ..I see no issues..make it Calendar.FRIDAY

Comment: `c` variable should be `cal`, even though that final value is not needed, since it's called directly in the `if` condition. You must use `Calendar.FRIDAY` and should consider Saturday as well.

Comment: Please edit the solution final int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); instead of final int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

Comment: @gRizzlyGR thanks for your comment

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ When I apply your solution for example when I put 2017/02/17 (friday) as a parameter in your method I get 2017/02/18 (satruday)instead of 2017/02/20 (monday)

Comment: I took your date as example and updated my answer, I can tell only so far is working...

Comment: You have modify many things on your code please take a look I have edited my post

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ did you see my update ?

Comment: yes... why are you using this  Date(int, int, int)), that is a deprecated method......

Answer (score 0):

Gets date instance and add no. of days excluding weekends. Set date to next monday if provided date is weekend.

```
public Date addDays(Date date, int days){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);

    //set date to next monday if provided date day is weekend
    //use this section according to your need.
    if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY){
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,2);
        //days-= 2;
    }else if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY){
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        //days--;
    }

    //add days one by one
    while(days > 0){
        //if current day is friday add 3 days to skip saturday and sunday
        if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY){
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE,3);
        //else add one day
        }else{
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        }
        //decrements day counter 
        days--;
    }

    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more your code !